# copying and fading HTML over to another spot on the page on hover

Tags: jquery

I am trying to copy the HTML from the title and description spans within each li into the info div below.  Preferably appending h2 tags around the title whilst fading it in.  If another li is hovered the current selection should fade out and the new one fade in...

HTML

```
   <li>
        <a class="sales1" href="#"><img alt="Sales" src="sample.png">
        <span class="drinkTitle">Test Title<span>
        <span class="drinkDesc">A test Description</span></span></a>
    </li>

<div id="drinksInfo"></div>
```

JQUERY

```
$('#drinksList ul li img').hover(function () {
      var str = $(this).siblings('.drinksTitle').text();
          $('#drinksInfo').html(str).fadein();
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What part is not working? What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/RC5sY/3/)**

```
    $('li').mouseover(function () {   
        var title = $(this).find('.drinkTitle').text(),
            descrip = $(this).find('.drinkDesc').text();

    if(!$(this).hasClass('selected')){
        $('.selected').removeClass('.selected');
        $(this).addClass('.selected');

        $('#drinksInfo').fadeOut(500, function(){
            $('#drinksInfo').html('<h2>' + title + '</h2>' + descrip).fadeIn(); 
        });  
    }
}
);
```

Comment: It seems to include an extra animation, its flashing...thank you for your input though

Comment: I got it working thanks, it was the drinksInfo div was not clearing the other bits so it was performing the wrong action...thanks Loktar

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can specify the duration for `fadeIn` effect as per your need.

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BVDJ5/1/)

```
 $(function(){

  $('#drinksList img').hover(function () {

      var str = $(this).siblings('.drinkTitle').text() + " " +
             $(this).siblings('.drinkDesc').text() ;
      $('#drinksInfo').html("<h2>"+str+"</h2>").hide().fadeIn(500);

  }, function(){
      $('#drinksInfo').fadeOut(500);
  });

});
```

Comment: No joy i am afraid... I was after just the h2 wrapping the title if possible.

Comment: Its just flashing at it me since i changed it to mouseover

Answer (score 0):

Lets have a try at it!

1. Your `<span class="drinkTitle">` is not properly closed
2. Your `sibling('.drinksTitle')` does not match `<span id="drinkTitle>`
3. It is fade**I**in instead of fade**i**n. (See the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/))
4. To get a fade in effect you need to hide the `<div>` first. This can be done in CSS using the `display: none` code.

Thats pretty much it I think. (except for the styling of the text in the `<div>` but that should not be a (real) problem.

Comment: @Andy: Guess all problems found, see my updated answer and the explanations.

Comment: Thanks Veger i changed all those bits, you were quite right.  Although it seems to be actioning it in firebug there is nothing getting pumped into the div...it is however correct classes now as you mentioned